# How to enable Prettier highlighting in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I have the Prettier extension installed in VS Code and it formats Javascript files correctly when I run `Format Document` from the command palette.  But it does not highlight / underline problems as I'm typing.  I've seen screenshots of this working for other people online.  How do I enable the real-time highlighting of problems?  I have Prettier set as the default formatter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [ESLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint). Prettier only formats. See also this plugins for a good job: [Babel](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mgmcdermott.vscode-language-babel), [Code Spell Checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker)